# android ZipArchiveEntry giving java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException

Tags: java, android, unicode, zipinputstream

I can unzip the 1st and 2nd entry of a zip file I am reading from the web, but then I get the MalformedInputException error. The zip file consists of unicode file names of mp3 files. I created the zip file that I placed on the web using Winzip (I tried both v11 and V18).

The mp3 files are all at the 'root' level in the zip file, i.e. not stored in subfolders.

I tried first with ZipInputStream. The last attempt (below) is with ArchiveInputStream. (I noticed that ArchiveInputStream didn't have a closeEntry() method like ZipInputStream - not that it made any difference).

The error always occurs on the line that gets the next entry.
     `while ((entry = (ZipArchiveEntry)zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null)`

The code is

```
    private void unizpMediaFile(String mediaDirectory, String zipFileURL) {
       InputStream inputStream = null;
       ArchiveInputStream zipStream = null;
       ArchiveEntry entry = null;
       try {
        // make sure can write to (probably) sd card
        File mediaFileDirectory = createMediaDirectory(mediaDirectory);
        if (mediaFileDirectory == null)
            return;
        inputStream = getHttpInputStream(zipFileURL);
        if (inputStream == null) {
            return;
        }
        zipStream =  new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream(ArchiveStreamFactory.ZIP,new BufferedInputStream(
                inputStream)   );
        while ((entry = (ZipArchiveEntry)zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Entry:" + entry.getName());
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                if (false == new File( mediaFileDirectory.getAbsoluteFile()
                        + File.separator + entry.getName()).mkdirs()) {
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mediaFileDirectory.getAbsoluteFile()
                 + File.separator + entry.getName());
                int size;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(
                         mediaFileDirectory.getAbsoluteFile()
                         + File.separator + entry.getName());
                BufferedOutputStream bufferOut = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        outStream, buffer.length);

                while ((size = zipStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                    bufferOut.write(buffer, 0, size);
                }
                bufferOut.flush();
                bufferOut.close();
                out.close();
                Log.i(TAG,"Entry:" + entry.getName() + " closed.");
            }
        }
        maintOpDetails.append(res.getString(R.string.load_complete));
        updateLoadDetails(maintOpDetails.toString() );
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "unizpMediaFile" + e.toString());
        storeErrorMessage(res.getString(R.string.error_reading_media_zip_file,
                zipFileURL, e.toString()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "unizpMediaFile" + e.toString());
        storeErrorMessage(res.getString(R.string.error_reading_media_zip_file,
                zipFileURL, e.toString()));
    } catch (ArchiveException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "unizpMediaFile" + e.toString());
        storeErrorMessage(res.getString(R.string.error_reading_media_zip_file,
                zipFileURL, e.toString()));
    }
    finally {
        if (inputStream != null){ try {inputStream.close();} catch (Exception e){} }
        if (zipStream != null){ try {zipStream.close();} catch (Exception e){} }
    }
}

private InputStream getHttpInputStream(String url) {
    HttpResponse response;
    InputStream is = null;
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://" + url);
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();
        BufferedHttpEntity buf;
        buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);
        is = buf.getContent();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getHttpInputStream" + e.toString());
        storeErrorMessage(res.getString(R.string.error_reading_file_at_url,
                url, e.toString()));
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException cte) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getHttpInputStream" + cte.toString());
        storeErrorMessage(res.getString(R.string.connect_timetout_error, url));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getHttpInputStream" + e.toString());
        storeErrorMessage(res.getString(R.string.error_reading_file_at_url,
                url, e.toString()));
    }
    return is;
}
```

From the log I get

```
I/LoadLanguageLessonService(3102): Entry:evet.mp3
I/LoadLanguageLessonService(3102): Entry:evet.mp3 closed.
I/LoadLanguageLessonService(3102): Entry:hay?r.mp3
I/LoadLanguageLessonService(3102): Entry:hay?r.mp3 closed.
E/LoadLanguageLessonService(3102): unizpMediaFilejava.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Length: 1
```

(The cut/paste from the log to here caused the unicode filename values to be converted to the '?' you see above.)

I checked out various SO postings with no luck.

Any ideas?

**Some followup**

I modified my code to first download the zip file to my phone and then unzip it from there. No luck doing it that way either.

I also used the following code

```
 ZipFile zipFile = null;
    try {
         zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFilename);
        Enumeration<?> enu = zipFile.entries();
        while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enu.nextElement();
            String name = zipEntry.getName();
            long size = zipEntry.getSize();
            long compressedSize = zipEntry.getCompressedSize();
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("name: %-20s | size: %6d | compressed size: %6d\n", 
                name, size, compressedSize));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
          throw e;
    }
```

to list all the entries in the zip file and found that the unicode characters all show up as a small black diamond with a question mark inside (after cut/paste into SO the characters show up just with the ? mark).

I also downloaded AndroZip and WinZip for Android and viewed the zip file via both apps on my phone. Again the unicode file names were corrupted.

At this point I am stuck. I think I will shift gears and see about downloading the files one by one.